# Eclipse Luna CDT fails in windows 64

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin

I've been installed Cygwin for windows x64.
After installation, I noticed that the system can find everything.

In the console:

```
C:\Users\Tomás>gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\Tomás>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\Tomás>make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

C:\Users\Tomás>gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.50.20130728-cvs (cygwin-special)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

Then, when I create a project in eclipse, I get this error message when you try to compile it:
[image: ECLIPSE LUNA ERROR]

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setup your compiler location.
You can do this in Project->Properties->C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Toolchains Tab.

For example, I use compiler from CodeSourcery Lite version.
So, I choose "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeSourcery\Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI\arm-none-eabi" in Global path field.

See image: https://yadi.sk/i/Zx_KkMs5X7TKg

In addition, You have some trouble in Node.cpp file...
But I need to see this file to say what's wrong...

Good Luck!

Vadim